# How can I set a custom user agent string for Cordova Android app?

Tags: java, android, cordova

I am trying to set a custom user agent string for my Cordova android application so that our web server can distinguish app requests coming from the app itself from requests coming from a browser on android.

Currently (based on answers to another SO question) I'm trying to do this by adding these lines to initWebViewSettings:

```
WebSettings settings = this.getSettings();
settings.setUserAgentString("CUSTOM-ANDROID-USER-AGENT");
```

This works on most requests, but on some requests I still get a generic user agent like this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; XT1034 Build/KXB21.14-L1.41) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/33.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

As a result, I don't have a reliable way of detecting the app. I don't know why I'm getting different user agent strings. Is there a better, more reliable way of setting a custom user agent? Or at least an alternative or additional way that I can experiment with?

Note there are answers to similar questions here on Stack Overflow, but either they are out of date or they are not explicit about where any changes need to be made (I do not know Java). I am on the latest version of Cordova (4.2).

Here is the context for what I am doing currently (thios is in `CordovaWebView.java`):

```
private void initWebViewSettings() {
        this.setInitialScale(0);
        this.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        // TODO: The Activity is the one that should call requestFocus().
        if (shouldRequestFocusOnInit()) {
            this.requestFocusFromTouch();
        }
        // Enable JavaScript
        WebSettings settings = this.getSettings();
        settings.setUserAgentString("CUSTOM-ANDROID-USER-AGENT");
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        settings.setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
```

Comment: can you give more details about the cases where you don't get the custom user agent? or is it random?

Comment: So I have a scenario where I transfer the user to my website (not in an iframe or anything, just the whole web view). So I'll get a number of requests (for the page, the javascript, the css, etc) as I would from a user coming to the site through a normal browser. Most of these requests are coming through with the custom user agent I specified, but each time one or two of the requests will come with the other user agent (I'm just logging them as they come in). It seems random.

Comment: Actually it seems to almost always be the first request that goes wrong, at or around the time it requests the app cache manifest.